# Creating Sprite in touchesBegan and then moves with UIPanGestureRecognizer but small delay

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm creating an app with `SpriteKit` which creates a `SKSpriteNode` object in the `touchesBegan` and then when you Pan across the screen, it moves the object along with it.

However, when I touch the screen, the sprite is created as expected and then when I move my finger; the sprite remains in the same place for small delay then moves to where my finger is.

My code is like below:

```
-(void)handlePan: (UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer{

if (([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) || ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged))
{

    CGPoint newLocation = [scene convertPointFromView:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view]];
    scene.finger.position = newLocation;


}
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    NSLog(@"Ended");

    [scene.finger removeFromParent];
    scene.finger = nil;
}
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [self convertPointFromView:[touch locationInView:self.view]];
    [self addFingerSprite:location];
}
```

}

Any idea, how I can fix this small delay issue?

Comment: try creating the sprite when the pan gesture is in the begin state and not when a touch began is detected

Comment: Hi giorashc, that's how I had it initially but then I wanted it to appear when you touch the screen and then move when you're pan on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay is caused by the use of a `PanGestureRecognizer`.  It takes a small time before the system recognizes that a pan is taking place.  Use `touchesMoved` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll see whether this works how I want it too. Cheers.